# NIC and username validation field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two fields, the NIC and the username. Their validation are

- NIC check for numbers or characters
- username field must contain more than 8 characters including the date
  of birth from the NIC.

So far I tried this for my NIC.

```js
function validateNIC() 
{
    var nic = document.getElementById('NIC');
    var mesg = document.getElementById('message1');

     if (NIC.length != 14) {
        message1.innerHTML="Length must be 14 characters";
    } else{
        message1.innerHTML="Length is good";
    }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username"><span class="req">* </span> NIC NUMBER:</label> 
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="NIC" id = "NIC" required onkeyup = "validateNIC();" maxlength=14  />  
                    <span id="message1"></span>
                        
            </div>
```

And for my username I tried this.

```js
function Validate(txt) {
  txt.value = txt.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z-'\n\r.]+/g, '');
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username"><span class="req">* </span> User name:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="txt" onkeyup="Validate(this)" maxlength=14 required />
  <div id="errLast"></div>
</div>
```

- My validation for the NIC is not quite working.It keeps showing
  "Length must be 14 characters" even if the length is good.
- And for the username part,  can anyone tell me how to do it ? Is
  there an array I must do or something ? An example of the NIC is
  T2108974302906 where 210897 is the DOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nic = document.getElementById('NIC');
var mesg = document.getElementById('message1');

if (NIC.length != 14) {
```

Here `NIC` refers to the DOM element, not the **value** of that input element.
You want to use `nic.value.length`.

As for the username, your RegEx looks strange `[^a-zA-Z-'\n\r.]`. This set matches characters that are not in the set. Why did you put `\n` and `\r`?

Anyway, if you are using a `<form>` element to submit these field, I suggest you use [pattern](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145) attribute. You can test yoru patterns on http://regex101.com/

To extract the DOB:

```
<input pattern="^T[0-3]\d[0-1]\d{10}$">

validateNIC() {
  var nic = document.getElementById('NIC');
  var isValid = /^T[0-3]\d[0-1]\d{10}$/.test(nic.value);
  var dob = nic.value.substring(1, 7);
}
```

Comment: For the username part , I am trying to extract the DOB from the NIC and autoplace it in the username field.

Comment: And how do you put the dob in the username field ?

Comment: This is for asking questions, now solving all of your problems at once.

Answer (score 0):

`var nic = document.getElementById('NIC');`

This statements gets the input element - not its value. You need to get its value as such:

`var nic = document.getElementById('NIC').value;`

Then, you can compare the length to 14. I would also suggest using `!==` instead of `!=`.

Username validation - why are you replacing the value if you're trying to validate? And why is your max value 14 and not 8?